# Is there a notation alternative to Hertz?

Tags: time, notation, frequency, si-units

Hertz, as we all know, is a unit of frequency where `1 Hz` equals `one cycle per second`. Conversely `3 Hz` is `three cycles per second` and `0.2 Hz` is `one cycle every five seconds`.

That last example can be quite hard to read. Knowing that `0.067 Hz` equals `once every 15 seconds` is not something you can immediately read.

Is there another notation you can use to signify that something occurs `every 15 seconds`, sort of life `"something" 15 sec` ? (I know I could use `1/15 Hz`, but I just don't like how it looks :)

And to be clear, I'm looking for some kind of symbol :)

Comment: 15 seconds is the *period* of oscillation. The period is the reciprocal of the frequency.

Comment: @G.Smith, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: 67 mHz.........

Comment: rpm - revolutions per minute; in your example 4.